# Custom Model binder not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders, model-binding

This is my custom model binder. I have my breakpoint set at BindModel but does not get fired with this controller action:

```
public ActionResult Create(TabGroup tabGroup)
```

...

```
public class BaseContentObjectCommonPropertiesBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public new object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
        }
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");
        }

        BaseContentObject obj = (BaseContentObject)base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        obj.Modified = DateTime.Now;
        obj.Created = DateTime.Now;
        obj.ModifiedBy = obj.CreatedBy = controllerContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        return obj;
    }
```

My registration:

// tried both of these two lines

```
ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(TabGroup)] = new BaseContentObjectCommonPropertiesBinder();
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(TabGroup), new BaseContentObjectCommonPropertiesBinder());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you used "new" keyword on BindModel method. The "new" means that method will not participate in virtual invocation (more about polymorphism you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx).

Replace "new" with "override" and it should work fine.

```
public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    //your stuff
}
```